# spectrum of convex combination

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

$A,B$ are $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices. If the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are all in an interval $I$, then the eigenvalues of any convex combination of $A,B$ are also in $I$.

In the book Bhatia, Matrix Analysis, the author says "This is an easy consequence of results in Chapter III.

From the answers (lemmas, in fact) to the question [Eigenvalues of Matrix Sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums) (mathoverflow) the statement follows easily.

However I would like to obtain a *direct* (possibly "simple") proof. If it is possible, for the infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces also.

Comment: We can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A_j$ are self-adjoint bounded operators on a Hilbert space with $\sigma(A_j) \subseteq [a,b]$, then $b I - A_j \ge 0$ and $A_j - a I \ge 0$, i.e. $\langle (bI - A_j) v, v \rangle \ge 0$ and $\langle ((A_j - a I) v, v \rangle \ge 0$ for all vectors $v$.  These properties are obviously preserved by convex combinations.

Comment: this is I wanted. Thanks.